# AWS RDS running slow

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a AWD RDS instance as AWD free plan.

The DB is postgres

I imported an existing owned DB and few days back it was working fine (as speed), now same queries take up to 3-5 more time to run.

This applies only for some queries but not all.

The AWD dashboard says that "Service is operating normally"

Do you know what might be the issue or how to troubleshoot the AWD RDS?

Comment: Free RDS instances are on micros, right? They get burst I/O with quotas. Most likely you've burned through your accumulated I/O savings pool and are now using new iops as fast as you're granted them.

Comment: i really doubt i burned the burst credit since i haven't used that db for 3 days, in the end i deleted the old db and copied again and now it works fine.